# Trying to get a Jquery sorting plug in to work, but it isn't

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I think I am really close to solving it but can't. The test site is here: http://testing.bdanzer.com/tabs/ I am trying to write my php to auto generate the page with portfolio pieces that will be sortable.

This is the code that will work with the sorting. Here is the jquery plug in I am trying to use: https://www.queness.com/post/14577/create-a-simple-responsive-portfolio-page-with-filtering-and-hover-effect . It's the default the jquery plug in uses.

```
<ul id="filters" class="clearfix">
    <li><span class="filter active" data-filter=".app, .card, .icon, .logo, .web">All</span></li>
    <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".app">App</span></li>
    <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".card">Card</span></li>
    <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".icon">Icon</span></li>
    <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".logo">Logo</span></li>
    <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".web">Web</span></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="portfoliolist">
      <div class="portfolio logo" data-cat="logo">
        <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to add some of that code into my php that generates the posts but it won't filter even if I add the classes and data:

```
    <dl id="" class="gridtab-1">
<?php 
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
    <dt class="portfolio logo" data-cat="logo"><div id="portfoliolist">
      <div class="portfolio logo" data-cat="logo">
        <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div></dt>

    <dd class="entry-content">
        <div class="bdanzer-container">
            <div class="bdanzer-left">
                <h1 style="text-align:center;">Thumbnails</h1>
                <div class="bdanzer-featured">
                  <a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" data-fancybox="<?php the_ID(); ?> " data-caption="Caption blah">
                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="" />
                  </a>
                </div>

                <div class="bdanzer-thumbnails">
                  <a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" data-fancybox="<?php the_ID(); ?> " data-caption="Caption #1">
                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="" />
                  </a>

                  <a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" data-fancybox="<?php the_ID(); ?> " data-caption="Caption #2">
                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="" />
                  </a>
                </div>



            </div>
            <div class="bdanzer-right">
                <h1 style="text-align:center;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                <p style="display:inline-block"><strong>Categories:</strong></p> <p style="display:inline-block"><?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </dd>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</dl>
```

What is it that I am doing wrong? I have another jquery plug in that will creating a google like drop down when you click the image. So maybe that is making it harder to figure this out. Any insight will be helpful.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you might try changing your data-filter names to NOT start with a period. I'm not sure if that would break it or not, but it doesn't seem like the best naming convention.

Comment: This is what I get when looking at the console : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).gridtab is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.eval (inline-1384dcfbb86.js:3:19)
    at j (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:1:29948)
    at k (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:1:30262)


Also, where does your dl tag end? It doesn't look like the snippet you provided shows a closing tag.

Comment: @Squeakasaur It's not filtering the <dt> tags. Those are the tags that need to filter if that makes sense.

Comment: added more code

Comment: You are trying to use .gridtab like a function which it isn't from what I can see :
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#gridtab-1').gridtab({
   grid:3
  });
 });

Comment: Also, you only have one picture so it is kind of hard to really filter....

Comment: The one image shouldn't matter. I am trying to filter the dl tags which doesn't mater what is inside.